# PostgreSQL Update Column based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, case, postgresql-9.1, coalesce

**Setting:**

I use PostgreSQL 9.1.2 and have a basic table as below, where I have 4 binary columns that can take on the values Y or N. These columns also largely contain Null values, which I have denoted as '-' in the table below:

```
    Binary Col 1   Binary Col 2   Binary Col 3   Binary Col 4   Summary Col
    ------------   ------------   ------------   ------------   -----------
1.       Y             N               -             N               1
2.       -             Y               N             Y               2
3.       N             N               -             N               0
4.       -             -               -             -               -
5.       Y             Y               Y             Y               4
```

**Problem:**

I want to include a *Summary Column* to my table which is filled based on the number of 'Y's that occur in these 4 binary columns. I gave 5 example entries in the table above to showcase the desired output. One important thing to note is that I want to be able to differentiate cases like entry 3 (no 'Y's observed) from cases like entry 4 (all binary columns are null). This is a one time effort and I do not have performance concerns as to how this duplicative column would affect the transactional speed of my table.

I looked into quite a few PostgreSQL "Update table" examples and also checked the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-update.html). However, I could not find an example of an update procedure with multiple conditions yet, which I believe is what is required here.

Or may be I am completely wrong and the solution requires an SQL function or a trigger, any tips or suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by binary column? What is its type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e9886/1)

```
select
    c1, c2, c3, c4,
        (coalesce(c1, '') = 'Y')::integer
        + (coalesce(c2, '') = 'Y')::integer
        + (coalesce(c3, '') = 'Y')::integer
        + (coalesce(c4, '') = 'Y')::integer
    total_Y,
        (c1 is null)::integer
        + (c2 is null)::integer
        + (c3 is null)::integer
        + (c4 is null)::integer
    total_null
from t
```

Comment: Thank you, I added 'coalesce' to the question's tags.

Answer (score 2):

As a happy coincidence, the sum function has exactly the behavior you are looking for. You just need to convert the values into rows:

```
UPDATE some_table SET summary = (SELECT SUM(v::int) FROM (VALUES (col1),(col2),(col3),(col4)) as x(v));
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain the logic?

Comment: The 4 columns are expanded as a single column relation with 4 rows, the boolean values are converted to int, false becoming 0 and true becoming 1, the values are then summed to return the desired result. This relies on the behavior of SQL sum aggregate that is defined to skip nulls and return null when all aggregated values are null.